# My div has a height of only 0px

Tags: javascript, html, css

My #root_menu_div has a height of 0px even though I have the following CSS rules:

```
#html{height:100%}
#body{height:100%}
#container{height:100%}
#body_container{height:100%}
#search{height:100%}

#root_menu_div {
min-height:100% !important; 
display:block !important; 
position:static !important;
}
```

The contents of #root_menu_div flow outside of its container (#search). So I think I have a height / position / display issue. It's behaving like I'm missing a closing tag, but I have them all.

Here is the url:
http://whiterootmedia.com/root_menu/index.html

Comment: does the parent element have its height property set?

Comment: So I guess 100% is just somewhere around 0px then? using `!important` is usually a sign of epic failure, and using it on all three styles, trice as much "epic fail".

Comment: Add `overflow:auto` to #root_menu_div. Fixed.

Comment: overflow:auto adds the scrollbar right? I don't think I want that right now...

Comment: @adeneo !important overrides inline css which is sometimes necessary

Comment: I'm having trouble following the code on the website. All I can say at the moment is that it's not reasonable to set every ancestor element to `height:100%`. Some of them have margins, padding, borders, or sibling elements that take up extra space in addition to the 100% height. That extra space gets added to the 100% height, which may cause some of the child elements to be taller than their parent.

Comment: No, `overflow:auto` does not add a scroll bar.

Comment: If nothing obvious turns up, create a trimmed-down version of the page, the simplest version of it possible (removing code) that still allows you to reproduce the problem. That should make it much easier to identify the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As @bfavaretto and @j08691 suggested, try the following:

```
html, body {height:100%;}
#root_menu_div {min-height:100%;}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/gPcgA/). Tested fine in IE7/8/9, FF, Safari, Chrome.

Comment: Both the html and body elements have their heights set to 100%... still stumped?

Comment: I had multiple containers with min-height:100% set, when it should be height:100%

My body and html tag had height:100%, but my #container and #body_container were set to min-height:100% which was incorrect.

I changed both #container and #body_container to height:100% and that did the trick.

I would like to understand why min-height:100% property failed to make the height 100%.

Comment: I thought these adjustments:`#container {height:100%}
#body_container {height:100%}` worked, but I don't think they did. My #root_menu_div is going outside its container (#search).

Comment: hmmm... what I tested in the jsFiddle demo above was a much simpler case, where `#root_menu_div` is a root-level div (directly inside the body tag) with no vertical margin, padding, or border -- testing the basic theory. But after taking more of a look at your website, it looks like the solution won't be as simple as this.

Comment: I should mention that #root_menu_div's only contents is my script `<script type="text/javascript" src="root_menu.js"></script>` this is why I'm throwing the `!important` on the css rules. Is there some sort of css property that allows text to flow outside its container that wouldn't be related to `display` or `position`.

Comment: Floating an element can cause this to happen. But it doesn't look like any of the main elements are floated. Take a look at the comment I added above (to your original question) about every ancestor element having `height:100%`. That's another thing that can cause this type of behavior.

Comment: Try getting rid of every `height:100%` and add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after `<div id="root_menu_div">...</div>` to clear any floated elements. I don't see any signs of elements being floated in Firebug, but doing this seemed to at least partially fix the problem.

Comment: I added text to that div and now it will take that text's height, but still wont take the height of that script.

Comment: `#root_menu_div` is taking `#search`'s `text-align:center;` property I think. Maybe I should rephrase my question and repost this with a JavaScript tag...

Answer (score 0):

You can't set height to 100% if it is relative to the browser window, unless you use javascript.

Comment: I believe this is correct. Setting `min-height` or `height` to 100% for a root-level div has no effect in any browser.

Comment: It does if the html and body tags have a height specified.

Comment: No, set `html, body { height: 100%; }` and child divs can be given full height.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Ahhh, yes, you're correct. It works if `html, body {height: 100%;}` and  `#root_menu_div {min-height:100%;}` are set. I guess that's the "solution" then.

Comment: @disagree: Notice how I said IF IT IS RELATIVE TO THE BROWSER WINDOW. Don't skim read, and you will be much happier in life.

Answer (score 0):

Everything contained within the div container is hidden.

You can add `&nbsp;` to the inner html of the div.